# How do I put a remove a leading space when printing something in java?

Tags: java, substring, indexof

**How do I put a remove a leading space when printing something in java?**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
public class InitialsProject {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        char firstInitial = name.charAt(0);
        int index = name.indexOf(" ");
        System.out.println(firstInitial + name.substring(index++,index+1));
   }
}
```

**Sample input:** John Doe

**Output:** J D

Comment: Use `name.substring(index+1,index+2)`

Comment: Or `name.substring(index + 1).charAt(0)`  However, you should check if `index > 0`

Answer (score 0):

So your question is a little vague, but I assume your issue is around "why does it print "J D" and not "JD""

The simple answer is `index++` is post operation, that is, the value of `index` is first used (by `substring`), then it's updated.  You could fix it by using a pre operation, ie `++index`, but I would suggest that using `index + 1` (and `index + 2`) is more readable and less error prone.

But...there are a number of ways you might perform this operation

For example, you could simply use `String#split`

```
String text = "John Doe";
String[] parts = text.split(" ");
if (parts.length == 1 && !parts[0].isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(parts[0].charAt(0));
} else if (parts.length == 2) {
    if (!parts[0].isEmpty() && !parts[1].isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(parts[0].charAt(0) + " " + parts[1].charAt(0));
    } else if (!parts[0].isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(parts[1].charAt(0));
    } else if (!parts[1].isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("..." + parts[1].charAt(0));
    } else {
        System.out.println(text + " is an invalid input");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println(text + " is an invalid input");
}
```

*nb: I'm been a little defensive, can't help it*

Or you could simply use `charAt` directly...

```
int index = text.indexOf(" ");
if (index >= 0) {
    if (index + 1 < text.length()) {
        System.out.println(text.charAt(0) + " " + text.charAt(index + 1));
    } else {
        System.out.println(text.charAt(0));
    }
} else {
    // Handle all the other possible conditions
}
```

Both the examples will print `J D`

Answer (score 0):

Simply using charAt would do the trick,

```
System.out.println(firstInitial + name.charAt(index+1));
```